# "No matching distribution" for pip install on WSL

Tags: python, pip, python-venv

I am using WSL2 Ubuntu on Windows 10 and trying to perform
`pip3 install django-tasks-scheduler`
but it returns:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-tasks-scheduler (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for django-tasks-scheduler
```

Same command works fine in my Windows' PowerShell

I've also tried `python3 -m pip install django-tasks-scheduler` but the result remained the same. My venv was created just after running `pip install --upgrade pip` and `pip install -U pip` inside of it.

Edit1:
`Python 3.8.10`
`Django==4.2.7`

Comment: Can you provide more information on which version of Python you are using (`python3 --version`) and maybe the django version ?

Comment: Python 3.8.10 and Django 4.2.7

Comment: This package requires [python 3.9 or higher](https://github.com/dsoftwareinc/django-tasks-scheduler/blob/a257e4154ecb4c0858854cf0659a3f99effa30cf/pyproject.toml#L47C2-L54)

Comment: Thank you, I've tried many things and did not think about that one. Upgrading python  version solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already noted in the comments, django-tasks-scheduler requires Python 3.9 or later. Even its earliest version, 1.0.0, requires Python 3.9 or later.

So if you want to use django-tasks-scheduler, you may want to install a newer version of Python than 3.8.

Presumably, in Windows Powershell, you are using a more recent version of Python, while your WSL Ubuntu has a default Python version of 3.8.